# "Отца не стало в июне." Why is Отца not Отец?

Tags: существительные, склонение

Shouldn't it be in nominative form, not (I assume) genitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*не стало + gen.* (literally, "it stopped being for smb. / smth.") means "this thing is not there anymore".

Compare:

> У меня нет машины // I don't have a car
>
> Вчера у меня не стало машины // Since yesterday I don't have a car anymore
>
> Вчера у меня не было машины // Yesterday I didn't have a car

*Отца не стало в июне* means "father is not there anymore since June", which is an euphemism for "father died in June".

Answer (score 3):

Nominative is mostly used when noun acts as a *subject*. In your case "father" is an *object*, and there is no subject at all. Such sentences are called *impersonal* since there is no distinct subject.

In English "there is"/"it is" or similar constructions are used for this.

No you could ask why the *accusative* is not used then, and the reason is "не стало чего-либо/кого-либо" simply demands noun in *genitive*. One could also try to invoke the negation rule that explains change of *accusative* to *genitive* in negated sentences but "стать" is not a transitive verb.